# Finding Records in a table using result of query of another table in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables

Groups:

```
id  group_name
--------------
1   G1
2   G2
3   G3
```

Permissions:

```
PersId  Groups_id
-----------------
10001   1
10001   2
10002   2
10003   3
```

This means 10001 can access to G1 and G2 and 10002 can access G2 and G3.

I want to write a query to find groups name that for example 10001 can access.

I have written a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Permissions 
WHERE PersId.id = [p_id]
```

but this query returns just 1 and 2. I want something to return G1 and G2

Comment: What is p_id? Are you referencing a control on a form? We can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Have you tried using a join operation?

Comment: [p_id] is a variable that when I open the query in access, an InputBox opens and asks me for entering then value. I can enter for example 10001 or 10002.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join two tables to get the right result like this :

```
SELECT Permissions.persid,group_name 
FROM       Permissions 
INNER JOIN Groups 
        ON Permissions.Groups_id = Groups.Id
WHERE Permissinos.PersId = 10001
```

This query will return the following output:

| persid | group_name |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | G1 |
| 10001 | G2 |